# Set linkbutton left to right in .net?

Tags: .net, asp.net, css

```
<tr>
    <td align="right">
        <div style="background-image: url(image/menustript.bmp); border-right: #ffffff 2px outset; border-top: #ffffff 2px outset; border-left: #ffffff 2px outset; border-bottom: #ffffff 2px outset;">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtn_home" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/image/homebutton.jpg" ImageAlign="Middle" OnClick="ibtn_home_Click" Height="21px"/>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtn_teacher"  runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/image/teacher.png" ImageAlign="Middle" width="90" OnClick="ibtn_teacher_Click"/>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtn_student"  runat="server"   ImageUrl="~/image/student.bmp" ImageAlign="Middle" OnClick="ibtn_student_Click" Height="21px"/>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtn_result" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/image/result.JPG" ImageAlign="Middle" OnClick="ibtn_result_Click" Height="21px"/>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtn_logoff" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/image/logout.bmp" ImageAlign="Middle" OnClick="ibtn_logoff_Click" height="21px"/>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

want to set like below

```
home | teacher | student | result |                                     logout
```

but, when admin login all menu should be like above..

but when student or even on home page. menu should be like,below

```
home | student | result
```

and when teacher login then menu shoulb be like , below

```
home | student | result |                                               logout
```

can anyone help me.. to set menu with css or without css..
but give me anything which is set menu like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .menuRow
    {
        background-image: url(image/menustript.bmp); 
        border-right: #ffffff 2px outset;
        border-top: #ffffff 2px outset; 
        border-left: #ffffff 2px outset; 
        border-bottom: #ffffff 2px outset;
    }
    .leftItem
    {
        float: left; display: block; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;
    }
</style>
<table>
    <tr class="menuRow">
        <td align="left">
                <asp:imagebutton id="ibtn_home" runat="server" imageurl="~/image/homebutton.jpg"
                    imagealign="Middle" onclick="ibtn_home_Click" height="21px" class="leftItem" />
                <asp:imagebutton id="ibtn_teacher" runat="server" imageurl="~/image/teacher.png"
                    imagealign="Middle" width="90" onclick="ibtn_teacher_Click" class="leftItem"/>
                <asp:imagebutton id="ibtn_student" runat="server" imageurl="~/image/student.bmp"
                    imagealign="Middle" onclick="ibtn_student_Click" height="21px" class="leftItem"/>
                <asp:imagebutton id="ibtn_result" runat="server" imageurl="~/image/result.JPG" imagealign="Middle"
                    onclick="ibtn_result_Click" height="21px" class="leftItem"/>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <asp:imagebutton id="ibtn_logoff" runat="server" imageurl="~/image/logout.bmp" imagealign="Middle"
                    onclick="ibtn_logoff_Click" height="21px" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: very good code. and a perfect one. as per i said. thanks a lot man. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

This is not really ideal, but you need to add to your image button a property CssClass.

Then set the following style on the class defined:

```
float: left; display: block; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;
```

Comment: this 3 condition must be satisfied and in your code division is going blank after logoff